# Path params is not working when i send as json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, routes

In routes i have some thing like this

```
  match '/*parent/:term/' => "parent#match" ,
```

Example when i hit this url in server it is coming like this

```
localhost:3000/women/jeans
```

the log when i hit html request

```
Parameters: {"parent"=> "women", "term"=>"jeans"}
```

the log when i hit json request(`localhost:3000/women/jeans.json`)

```
Parameters: {"parent"=>{}, "term"=>"jeans"}
```

I dont know why the parent param is null when i send as json

Comment: Long shot but try changing `match '/*parent/:term/'` to `match '/*parent/:term'`, without the trailing slash.

Comment: I suspect it's the different route that's to blame, rather tnan whether you do it with ajax or not.  You can do the .json one in the browser address bar too.  Do `rake routes` at the console and see if it's generated a route for the `.format` case:  the `:resources` approach does this but i don't know if the `match` approach does.

Comment: @MaxWilliams there is no other route which will match to this one.

Comment: Thq question is more whether the route you set up matches, and the addition of .format might be breaking it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other routes before your `match` that maybe matching your URL?

I've just tried this and everything looks just fine:

```
# routes.rb
match '/*parent/:term/' => 'parent#match', via: :get

# Generates:
  GET    /*parent/:term(.:format)                      parent#match

# http://localhost:3000/women/jeans
{"parent"=>"women", "term"=>"jeans"}

# http://localhost:3000/women/jeans.json
{"parent"=>"women", "term"=>"jeans", "format"=>"json"}
```

Looks like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Uzebekjon value is coming as a proxy request from wap server

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what value? Anyhow, the problem seems to be not related to your original question.

Comment: path param value is not coming .kind of weird problem.